# DataGridView с фильтрацией как в Excel

Tags: c#, winforms

Как мне сделать в WinForms Таблицу DataGridView с фильтрацией, чтобы нажимая правой кнопкой мыши по столбцу открывалось контекстное меню и предлагало выбрать или ввести параметры для фильтра. Прямо Как в Excel.

Comment: Просто интересно, почему вы не приняли ни одного ответа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так годится?
https://github.com/DartAlex/DataGridViewWithFilter/wiki

[image: DataGridViewWithFilter]

Есть вики и там же готовая dll-ка.

Пример:

1) Подключаем DataGridViewWithFilter.dll;

2) DataGridViewWithFilter наследник DataGridView:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Size = new Size(480, 480);
    // создаём датагрид
    DataGridViewWithFilter DG = new DataGridViewWithFilter();
    // размеры
    DG.Bounds = new Rectangle(10, 10, 445, 420);
    DG.Anchor = ((AnchorStyles)(((AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left) | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom)));
    DG.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    // добаляем датагрид на форму
    this.Controls.Add(DG);
    // заполняем данными
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    DT.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
    DT.Columns.Add("Name");
    DT.Columns.Add("Ver");
    DT.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
    DT.Rows.Add("1", "Ubuntu", "11.10", "13.10.2011");
    DT.Rows.Add("2", "Ubuntu LTS", "12.04", "18.10.2012");
    DT.Rows.Add("3", "Ubuntu", "12.10", "18.10.2012");
    DT.Rows.Add("4", "Ubuntu", "13.04", "25.04.2012");
    DT.Rows.Add("5", "Ubuntu", "13.10", "17.10.2013");
    DT.Rows.Add("6", "Ubuntu LTS", "14.04", "23.04.2014");
    DT.Rows.Add("7", "Ubuntu", "14.10", "23.10.2014");
    DT.Rows.Add("8", "Ubuntu", "15.04", "23.04.2015");

    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    DS.Tables.Add(DT);

    DG.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
}
```

В DataGridViewWithFilter.dll четыре класса:

**ColumnFilterClickedEventArg**

Событие нажатия на кнопку фильтрации:

```
public class ColumnFilterClickedEventArg : EventArgs
{
    public int ColumnIndex { get; private set; }
    public Rectangle ButtonRectangle { get; private set; }
    public ColumnFilterClickedEventArg(int colIndex, Rectangle btnRect)
    {
         this.ColumnIndex = colIndex;
         this.ButtonRectangle = btnRect;
     }
}
```

**DataGridFilterHeader**

Наследик DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell, тут мы добавим в заголовок кнопку фильтрации и привяжем событие:

```
public class DataGridFilterHeader : DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
{
    // состояние кнопки
    ComboBoxState currentState = ComboBoxState.Normal;
    Point cellLocation;
    Rectangle buttonRect;

    public event EventHandler<ColumnFilterClickedEventArg> FilterButtonClicked;
    // расширим заголовок на 20 пикселей что бы вставить туда кнопку
    protected override void OnDataGridViewChanged()
    {
        try
        {
            Padding dropDownPadding = new Padding(0, 0, 20, 0);
            this.Style.Padding = Padding.Add(this.InheritedStyle.Padding, dropDownPadding);
        }
        catch { }
        base.OnDataGridViewChanged();
    }
    // рисуем кнопку
    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics,
                              Rectangle clipBounds,
                              Rectangle cellBounds,
                              int rowIndex,
                              DataGridViewElementStates dataGridViewElementState,
                              object value,
                              object formattedValue,
                              string errorText,
                              DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
                              DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
                              DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds,
               cellBounds, rowIndex,
               dataGridViewElementState, value,
               formattedValue, errorText,
               cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);

        int width = 20;
        buttonRect = new Rectangle(cellBounds.X + cellBounds.Width - width, cellBounds.Y, width, cellBounds.Height);
        cellLocation = cellBounds.Location;
        ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(graphics, buttonRect, currentState);
    }
    // анимация нажатия
    protected override void OnMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsMouseOverButton(e.Location))
            currentState = ComboBoxState.Pressed;
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsMouseOverButton(e.Location))
        {
            currentState = ComboBoxState.Normal;
            this.OnFilterButtonClicked();
        }
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }
    private bool IsMouseOverButton(Point e)
    {
        Point p = new Point(e.X + cellLocation.X, e.Y + cellLocation.Y);
        if (p.X >= buttonRect.X && p.X <= buttonRect.X + buttonRect.Width &&
        p.Y >= buttonRect.Y && p.Y <= buttonRect.Y + buttonRect.Height)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    // активируем событие
    protected virtual void OnFilterButtonClicked()
    {
        if (this.FilterButtonClicked != null)
        {
            this.FilterButtonClicked(this, new ColumnFilterClickedEventArg(this.ColumnIndex, this.buttonRect));
        }
    }
}
```

**FilterStatus**

В таком виде будем хранить состояние фильтров:

```
class FilterStatus
{
    // имя колонки
    public string columnName { get; set; }
    // значение ячейки
    public string valueString { get; set; }
    // состояние фильтра
    public bool check { get; set; }
}
```

**DataGridViewWithFilter**

Наследник DataGridView, тут и происходит вся магия:

```
public class DataGridViewWithFilter : DataGridView
{
    // в этом списке будет состяние фильтров
    List<FilterStatus> Filter = new List<FilterStatus>();
    // элементы всплывающего меню
    //   TextBox для поиска значений
    TextBox textBoxCtrl = new TextBox();
    //   DateTimePicker для поиска даты
    DateTimePicker DateTimeCtrl = new DateTimePicker();
    //   CheckedListBox для выбора фильтров
    CheckedListBox CheckCtrl = new CheckedListBox();
    //   кнопки "Применить" и "Очистить"
    Button ApplyButtonCtrl = new Button();
    Button ClearFilterCtrl = new Button();
    //   и всплывающее меню
    ToolStripDropDown popup = new ToolStripDropDown();

    // надписи в меню
    string StrFilter = "";
    string ButtonCtrlText = "Apply";
    string ClearFilterCtrlText = "Clear filters";
    string CheckCtrlAllText = "All";

    // из события получаем номер колонки
    private int columnIndex { get; set; }

    // при добавлении колонок в DataGridView заменяем заголовки на новые
    protected override void OnColumnAdded(DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        var header = new DataGridFilterHeader();
        header.FilterButtonClicked += new EventHandler<ColumnFilterClickedEventArg>(header_FilterButtonClicked);
        e.Column.HeaderCell = header;
        base.OnColumnAdded(e);
    }

    // показываем меню при нажатии на кнопку фильтрации
    void header_FilterButtonClicked(object sender, ColumnFilterClickedEventArg e)
    {
        // размеры меню
        int widthTool = GetWhithColumn(e.ColumnIndex) + 50;
        if (widthTool < 110) widthTool = 110;

        columnIndex = e.ColumnIndex;

        textBoxCtrl.Clear();
        CheckCtrl.Items.Clear();
        // создаём элементы контекстного меню и переопределяем события
        textBoxCtrl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(widthTool, 30);
        textBoxCtrl.TextChanged -= textBoxCtrl_TextChanged;
        textBoxCtrl.TextChanged += textBoxCtrl_TextChanged;

        DateTimeCtrl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(widthTool, 30);
        DateTimeCtrl.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        DateTimeCtrl.CustomFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";
        DateTimeCtrl.TextChanged -= DateTimeCtrl_TextChanged;
        DateTimeCtrl.TextChanged += DateTimeCtrl_TextChanged;

        CheckCtrl.ItemCheck -= CheckCtrl_ItemCheck;
        CheckCtrl.ItemCheck += CheckCtrl_ItemCheck;
        CheckCtrl.CheckOnClick = true;
        // получаем список сохранённых фильтров для CheckListBox
        GetChkFilter();

        CheckCtrl.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(widthTool, GetHeightTable() - 120);
        CheckCtrl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(widthTool, (CheckCtrl.Items.Count + 1) * 18);

        ApplyButtonCtrl.Text = ButtonCtrlText;
        ApplyButtonCtrl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(widthTool, 30);
        ApplyButtonCtrl.Click -= ApplyButtonCtrl_Click;
        ApplyButtonCtrl.Click += ApplyButtonCtrl_Click;

        ClearFilterCtrl.Text = ClearFilterCtrlText;
        ClearFilterCtrl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(widthTool, 30);
        ClearFilterCtrl.Click -= ClearFilterCtrl_Click;
        ClearFilterCtrl.Click += ClearFilterCtrl_Click;
        // теперь заполняем контекстное меню
        popup.Items.Clear();
        popup.AutoSize = true;
        popup.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        popup.Padding = Padding.Empty;

        ToolStripControlHost host1 = new ToolStripControlHost(textBoxCtrl);
        host1.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        host1.Padding = Padding.Empty;
        host1.AutoSize = false;
        host1.Size = textBoxCtrl.Size;

        ToolStripControlHost host2 = new ToolStripControlHost(CheckCtrl);
        host2.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        host2.Padding = Padding.Empty;
        host2.AutoSize = false;
        host2.Size = CheckCtrl.Size;

        ToolStripControlHost host3 = new ToolStripControlHost(ApplyButtonCtrl);
        host3.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        host3.Padding = Padding.Empty;
        host3.AutoSize = false;
        host3.Size = ApplyButtonCtrl.Size;

        ToolStripControlHost host4 = new ToolStripControlHost(ClearFilterCtrl);
        host4.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        host4.Padding = Padding.Empty;
        host4.AutoSize = false;
        host4.Size = ClearFilterCtrl.Size;

        ToolStripControlHost host5 = new ToolStripControlHost(DateTimeCtrl);
        host5.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        host5.Padding = Padding.Empty;
        host5.AutoSize = false;
        host5.Size = DateTimeCtrl.Size;
        // если в столбце даты, то в качестве поля поиске DateTimePicker,
        // иначе TextBox
        switch (this.Columns[columnIndex].ValueType.ToString())
        {
            case "System.DateTime":
                popup.Items.Add(host5);
                break;
            default:
                popup.Items.Add(host1);
                break;
        }
        popup.Items.Add(host2);
        popup.Items.Add(host3);
        popup.Items.Add(host4);

        popup.Show(this, e.ButtonRectangle.X, e.ButtonRectangle.Bottom);
        host2.Focus();
    }
    // первый CheckBox "выбрать всё", соответственно заполняем все
    // CheckBox'ы как первый
    void CheckCtrl_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index == 0)
        {
            if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < CheckCtrl.Items.Count; i++)
                    CheckCtrl.SetItemChecked(i, true);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < CheckCtrl.Items.Count; i++)
                    CheckCtrl.SetItemChecked(i, false);
            }
        }
    }
    // кнопка очистить фильтры
    void ClearFilterCtrl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Filter.Clear();
        StrFilter = "";
        ApllyFilter();
        popup.Close();
    }
    // быстрый поиск по тексту
    void textBoxCtrl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (this.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("convert([" + this.Columns[columnIndex].Name + "], 'System.String') LIKE '%{0}%'", textBoxCtrl.Text);
    }
    // быстрый поиск по дате
    void DateTimeCtrl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (this.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("convert([" + this.Columns[columnIndex].Name + "], 'System.String') LIKE '%{0}%'", DateTimeCtrl.Text);
    }
    // кнопка применить фильтры
    void ApplyButtonCtrl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StrFilter = "";
        SaveChkFilter();
        ApllyFilter();
        popup.Close();
    }
    // получаем список значений в колонке, сортируем и убираем дубли
    private List<string> GetDataColumns(int e)
    {
        List<string> ValueCellList = new List<string>();
        string Value;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.Rows)
        {
            Value = row.Cells[e].Value.ToString();

            if (!ValueCellList.Contains(Value))
                ValueCellList.Add(row.Cells[e].Value.ToString());
        }
        return ValueCellList;
    }

    private int GetHeightTable()
    {
        return this.Height;
    }

    private int GetWhithColumn(int e)
    {
        return this.Columns[e].Width;
    }
    // сохраняем состояние фильтров
    private void SaveChkFilter()
    {
        string col = this.Columns[columnIndex].Name;
        string itemChk;
        bool statChk;

        Filter.RemoveAll(x => x.columnName == col);

        for (int i = 1; i < CheckCtrl.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            itemChk = CheckCtrl.Items[i].ToString();
            statChk = CheckCtrl.GetItemChecked(i);
            Filter.Add(new FilterStatus() { columnName = col, valueString = itemChk, check = statChk });
        }
    }
    // заполнение CheckListBox
    private void GetChkFilter()
    {
        List<FilterStatus> CheckList = new List<FilterStatus>();
        List<FilterStatus> CheckListSort = new List<FilterStatus>();
        // добавляем то уже сохранено
        foreach (FilterStatus val in Filter)
        {
            if (this.Columns[columnIndex].Name == val.columnName)
            {
                CheckList.Add(new FilterStatus() { columnName = "", valueString = val.valueString, check = val.check });
            }
        }
        // и смотрим всё что осталось в колонке
        foreach (string ValueCell in GetDataColumns(columnIndex))
        {
            int index = CheckList.FindIndex(item => item.valueString == ValueCell);
            if (index == -1)
            {
                CheckList.Add(new FilterStatus { valueString = ValueCell, check = true });
            }
        }
        // выводим в CheckedListBox
        CheckCtrl.Items.Add(CheckCtrlAllText, CheckState.Indeterminate);
        // сортировка
        // Int32 сортируется как 1,12,2,21
        // приведём сортировку к 1,2,12,21
        switch (this.Columns[columnIndex].ValueType.ToString())
        {
            case "System.Int32":
                CheckListSort = CheckList.OrderBy(x => Int32.Parse(x.valueString)).ToList();
                foreach (FilterStatus val in CheckListSort)
                {
                    if (val.check == true)
                        CheckCtrl.Items.Add(val.valueString, CheckState.Checked);
                    else
                        CheckCtrl.Items.Add(val.valueString, CheckState.Unchecked);
                }
                break;
            // даты тоже сортируем отдельно
            case "System.DateTime":
                CheckListSort = CheckList.OrderBy(x => DateTime.Parse(x.valueString)).ToList();
                foreach (FilterStatus val in CheckListSort)
                {
                    if (val.check == true)
                       CheckCtrl.Items.Add(DateTime.Parse(val.valueString).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), CheckState.Checked);
                    else
                        CheckCtrl.Items.Add(DateTime.Parse(val.valueString).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), CheckState.Unchecked);
                }
                break;
            // всё что осталось - просто текст
            default:
                CheckListSort = CheckList.OrderBy(x => x.valueString).ToList();
                foreach (FilterStatus val in CheckListSort)
                {
                    if (val.check == true)
                        CheckCtrl.Items.Add(val.valueString, CheckState.Checked);
                    else
                        CheckCtrl.Items.Add(val.valueString, CheckState.Unchecked);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    // ну и показываем в табличке всё что насортировали
    private void ApllyFilter()
    {
        foreach (FilterStatus val in Filter)
        {
            if (val.check == false)
            {
                if (StrFilter.Length == 0)
                {
                    StrFilter = StrFilter + ("[" + val.columnName + "] <> '" + val.valueString + "' ");
                }
                else
                {
                    StrFilter = StrFilter + (" AND [" + val.columnName + "] <> '" + val.valueString + "' ");
                }
            }
        } 
        (this.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = StrFilter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Answer (score 1):

Здесь подробно описано как создать фильтр
[Drop-Down Filter List for a DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480727.aspx).
Но при больших данных (Более 20,000 уникальных записей) немного тормозит.

Answer (score 0):

Добавить компонент контекстного меню. Создать в нем меню. Привязать компонент к DataGridView. Назначить действия при выборе соответствующих меню :)

Особенности: если прям как в Excel -то надо обработать нажатие правой кн.мышки, чтоб выделялась ячейка на которой находится курсор. Ну и в функциях уже брать выделенную колонку, строку или что там вам надо из грида и выполнять действия.

PS: сама фильтрация происходит не в гриде, а в компоненте который поставляет данные для отображения в гриде (к примеру BindingSource, который привязан к таблице DataTable)

Comment: И что же мне для каждого столба контекстное меню делать?

Comment: Нет. Контекстное меню назначается общим для всего DataGridView.
В контекстном меню в обработчике нажатия на конкретное меню, пишете код ориентируясь на текущие выделенные данные в DataGridView. К примеру DataGridView.CurrentRow и т.п.. там можно и номер строки вытащить и столбец, и название и все необходимые данные для фильтра.
Сформировав строку фильтра применяете его на соответствующем компоненте как например BindingSource.Filter = название_текущей_колонки = 'Значание_из_выделенной_ячейки'

Почитайте про эти компоненты на MSDN или в инете примеры гляньте. Тут главное направление указали.

Comment: В принципе я вам указал примерную последовательность действий, просто код привести не могу для примера. На работе дел полно, некогда сидеть ради примерчика которых полно в нете, создавать проект :)